# How To Parse XML With Invalid Characters in Node Name?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, invalid-characters

So I'm trying to parse some XML, the creation of which is not under my control.  The trouble is, they've somehow got nodes that look like this:

```
<ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(MORNINGSTAR) />
<ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(QUARTERSTAFF) />
<ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(SCYTHE) />
<ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(TRATNYR) />
<ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(TRIPLE-HEADED_FLAIL) />
<ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(WARAXE) />
```

Visual Studio and .NET both feel that the '(' and ')' characters, as used above, are totally invalid.  Unfortunately, I need to process these files! Is there any way to get the Xml Reader classes to not freak out at seeing these characters, or dynamically escape them or something?  I could do some sort of pre-processing on the whole file, but I DO want the '(' and ')' characters if they appear inside the node in some valid way, so I don't want to just remove them all...

Comment: If is invalid then is not XML. Period. Process it as text.

Comment: This file looks like it is supposed to be preprocessed by some other tool before it gets sent to an xml parser.  ID_INTERNAL_FEAT_FOCUSED_EXPERTISE_(MORNINGSTAR) looks like a lookup for what is actually supposed to be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That simply isn't valid. Pre-processing is your best-bet, perhaps with regex - something like:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(<\w+)\((\w+)\)([ >/])", "$1$2$3");
```

Edit: a bit more complex to replace the "-" inside the brackets:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(<\w+)\(([-\w]+)\)([ >/])",
    delegate(Match match) {
        return match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value.Replace('-', '_')
             + match.Groups[3].Value;
    });
```

Comment: I would try for the most restrictive regex possible

Comment: @Dolphin - care to provide a concrete suggestion?

Comment: The regex mostly works, but somehow the second-to-last node in the above example survives with '(' and ')' intact :\

Comment: Thanks.  I'm the third-party to this XML document, so I'm not really in a position to demand fixes to it.  But with the regex, now it works.

Answer (score 3):

If it isn't syntactically valid, it's not XML.

XML is very strict about this.

If you can't get the sending application to send correct XML, then just let them know that *whatever* downstream process sees this *will fail*, whether it's yours or some other app in the future.

If preprocessing isn't an option, another clever mechanism is to wrap the `Stream` object that is passed to the parser with a custom stream. That stream could look for `<` characters, and when it sees one, set a flag. Until a `>` character is see, it could eat any `(` or `)` characters. We've used something like this to get rid of NUL and ^Z characters added to an XML file by a legacy transport mechanism. (The only gotcha there might be `<` characters inside of an attribute, since they don't have to be escaped there - only `>` characters do.)